# How to set selected row programmatically in Kendo Grid + Angular 4?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have app on Angular 4 + TypeScript + Kendo UI. Also I have a page with table of users. After editing user I want to highlight user by **ID** that I edited.

```
users: Observable<Array<User>>;
selectedId: number;    
gridView: GridDataResult;

ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => {
            this.selectedId = +params['id'];
            return this.adminService.getUsers();
        });
    });
}
```

Also I found in Kendo documentation event with "*index*" and "*selected*" fields:

```
selectionChange(event: SelectionEvent): void {
    //?
}
```

I tried to call `selectionChange` programmatically in `ngOnInit` method:

```
this.selectionChange({ index: 1, selected: true });
```

But I don't know what to do to set selected row in `gridView` in body of `selectionChange` method.

So, what should I do with `gridView` to select row? Or may be there is a simpler method to select row by **ID**.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the row manually as below, I have tried in my Kendo grid it works but it may required some polishing.

Define some required **variables**: (please define missing variables from below code)

```
rowIndex : number =0;
isSelectedRowChanged: boolean = false;
selectedItem : any;
```

Define **Function** to set selected row as below:

```
public SetSelectedRow(index: number, isManualSelection, isSelected, isCellClick) {

    var grid = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('k-grid-content')[0];
    var rows = grid.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    let dataRowIndex = -1;
    let selectedRow = grid.getElementsByClassName('k-state-selected')[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (rows[i].className.indexOf("k-grouping-row") < 0 && rows[i].className.indexOf("k-group-footer") < 0) {

            if (isManualSelection) {
                this.rowIndex = 1;

                if (selectedRow != null) {
                    selectedRow.className = String(selectedRow.className).replace(" k-state-selected", '').replace("k-state-selected", '');
                }
                if (rows[i].className.indexOf("k-state-selected") < 0) {
                    rows[i].click();
                }

                //Set selectedItem
                for (let k = 0; k < rows[i].children.length; k++) {
                    if (rows[i].children[k].className.indexOf("k-group-cell") < 0 && rows[i].children[k].children[0] != null) {                            
                        rows[i].children[k].children[0].click();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            } else {
                if (this.isSelectedRowChanged) {
                    this.rowIndex = index + 1;
                    return;
                }
                if (selectedRow == null) {
                    //Set selectedItem
                    rows[i].className = rows[i].className + " k-state-selected";
                    for (let k = 0; k < rows[i].children.length; k++) {

                        if (rows[i].children[k].className.indexOf("k-group-cell") < 0 && rows[i].children[k].children[0] != null) {                                
                            rows[i].children[k].children[0].click();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    dataRowIndex++;
                    if (!this.isSelectedRowChanged) {
                        if (isSelected && !isCellClick) {
                            selectedRow.click();
                        }

                        break;
                    } else {
                        this.rowIndex = dataRowIndex + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Call below function to set first row selected after assign Data source to grid:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
        this.rowIndex = 0;
        this.SetSelectedRow(0, true, false, false);
    }, 200);
```

Write below function on **Row Selection Change Event**:

```
 public OnSelection_Changed(item: any): void {
    if (!item.selected) {
        this.SetSelectedRow(item.index, false, true, false);
    }
    else {
        this.SetSelectedRow(item.index, false, false, false);
    }        
}
```

Also define **Cell Click event**:

```
OnCellClick(dataItem, rowIndex, columnIndex) { 
    if (this.selectedItem != dataItem) {
        this.isSelectedRowChanged = true;
        this.selectedItem = dataItem;            
    }
    else {
        this.isSelectedRowChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My temp solution is:

Insert attribute **data-id** in html:

```
<kendo-grid-column title="Actions">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-user>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit User" [attr.data-id]="user.id"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

And in ts:

```
gridView: GridDataResult;
selectedId: number;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private adminService: AdminService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => {
            this.selectedId = +params['id'];
            return this.adminService.getUsers();
        })
        .subscribe((response: GridDataResult) => {
            this.gridView = response;
            this.selectRow();
        });
}


selectRow() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.selectedId) {
            let button = document.querySelector('[data-id="' + this.selectedId + '"]');
            if (button) {
                let tr = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
                tr.className += " k-state-selected";
            }
        }
    }, 200);
}
```